# Change page background on click to match color of clicked page element using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am following the tutorial here https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/cd-beginner-javascript-sushi/8 to make a guess the color game. The last part is a challenge to change the page background when the correct color is guessed. I've managed to change the background but it only returns the color of the last button on the page, not the correct button. Here is a codepen to demonstrate: https://codepen.io/nicdaslick/pen/QWbogQQ.

I understand what's happening, but not how to fix it. The code is inside a for loop but the suggestion in the challenge hints is to change the color inside the for loop. How do I grab the right colors or am I thinking about this wrong?

html:

```
<body>
<h1>Guess the colour!</h1>
    <h2 id="colourValue"></h2>
    <div id="buttonWrapper">
        <button class="colourButton"></button>
        <button class="colourButton"></button>    
        <button class="colourButton"></button>    
        <button class="colourButton"></button>    
        <button class="colourButton"></button>    
        <button class="colourButton"></button>    
    </div>
    <h2 id="answer"></h2>

    <div id="reset"><button id="resetButton">Reset game</button></div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.colourButton{
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: none;
    margin: 10px;
}

#buttonWrapper{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
}

#colourValue{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#answer{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#reset{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#reset-button{
    padding: 10px;
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

js:

```
function makeColourValue(){
  return Math.round(Math.random()*255);
}

function setButtonColour(button, red, green, blue) {
  button.setAttribute(
    'style',
    'background-color: rgb('+ red +','+ green +','+ blue +');'
  );
}

var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('colourButton');

var heading = document.getElementById('colourValue');

var answerMessage = document.getElementById('answer');

function startGame() {
  answerMessage.innerHTML = "";
  var answerButton = Math.round(Math.random() * (buttons.length - 1));

  for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var red = makeColourValue();
    var green = makeColourValue();
    var blue = makeColourValue();

    setButtonColour(buttons[i], red, green, blue);

    if (i === answerButton) {
      heading.innerHTML =`(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})`;
    }

    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      if (this === buttons[answerButton]) {
        answerMessage.innerHTML = "Correct!";
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+ red +','+ green+','+ blue+')';
      } else {
        answerMessage.innerHTML = "Wrong answer! Guess again!";
      }
    });
  }
}

startGame();

document.getElementById('resetButton').addEventListener('click', startGame);
```

Comment: That's better to use element.style.backgroudColor than append then attribute

Answer (score 1):

One problem is your use of `var` instead of `let` or `const`.

When you declare a variable with `var`, it makes a *function-scoped variable*, no matter *where* you declare it. Therefore, inside your for loop, `red`, `green`, and `blue` all refer to the same values for each iteration of the loop, rather that you having a distinct value per loop iteration. Think of these variables as being hoisted and declared in the top of your `startGame` function.

Changing those to `const` or `let` should make the variables *block-scoped*, so they'll exist within the scope of the `for` loop. This will allow your event listeners which are also declared within the loop to close over unique values per iteration.

I would implore you to *never use `var` ever again*; it has no redeeming qualities over what `let` or `const` provide other than allowing your code to run in ancient browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `event` object to your function. Then access the style with `event.target.style`

```
buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
      if (this === buttons[answerButton]) {
        answerMessage.innerHTML = "Correct!";
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = event.target.style.backgroundColor
      } else {
        answerMessage.innerHTML = "Wrong answer! Guess again!";
      }
})
```